# How can I change the ppi of an image in GIMP?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, gimp

I want to transform the images (of any size) to A3 size and I am using GIMP? 
Its only showing the 72ppi option but I want to increase it to 330 or more than 72ppi. Its not showing any option to edit?

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this in the Print Size settings, accessible via Image -> Print Size.

http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-print-size.html

Please note that this will not change the image content. In particular, it will not increase or decrease the number of pixels in your image.

For A3 at 330 ppi, you will need an image size of about 3858 * 5455 pixels.